ASP.NET MVC : Rich Text Box With Custom Context Menu
I am looking to incorporate a rich text editing feature into a on premise application of mine developed using ASP.NET MVC.
In addition to the rich text editing features, the users shall also enter place holders in a predefined format, these place holders shall have a name that is used as a Identifier in the database. On click of these place holders a context menu should popup containing all the values of against the Identifier in DB.
Example: In DB Table the data is



Identifier
values




Sales
Channel Sales


Sales
Partner Sales


Sales
Direct Sales


Sales
SaaS Sales


Procurement
Services


Procurement
Centralized


Procurement
Standard


Procurement
Blanket


Invoice
Credit


Invoice
Debit



and on the Rich Text Box

The Sales has been sucessfully done and the Procurement has been inline with the standard procedures. An Invoice has to be raise to the vendor. These Sales Shall be repeated after 6 months

Now in the rich text box if the Sales in the first line is clicked, in the context menu with all the values from the table whose Identifier is sales and so on. On click of any of the values from context menu the same should be replaced in the editor for the selected word only, in this case the Sales in the first line, the Sales in second line should remain as is.
From the code I should be able to save this Rich text as a RTF and a PDF with pagination and should be able to read & load it when necessary.
This RTE needs to be a On Premise / Embeddable into ASP.NET MVC views, not a cloud based solution.
I have been checking some of the RTE on the internet and came across CKEDitor, TinyMCE, QuillJS. But none of them seem to be providing any feature to have the context menu from DB as described above.
Please Advice.
